# AWS Kubernetes cluster creating extra ebs volumes in available state

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, amazon-ebs

I have a kubertnetes cluster in aws eks.. and with it I have an autoscaling group policy attached to have 3 ec2 instances running. With each instance 1 ebs volume is created when it is launched every-time.

- However recently with a change(that I dont know of) 1 of the 3 instances, started to create 4 ebs volumes with it when it launches... one ebs volume has the "deletion on termination" YES so it deletes.. but the other 3 ebs extra volumes not in-use dont have the "deletion on termination" YES - they have NO
- because of this I have 3000+ extra ebs volumes created and just sitting in ebs volumes with 'available' state.. not being used and giving me cost $$$
- Now I do not know from where and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Kubernetes adds some tags to the volumes. Do you see some tags on the volumes?

Comment: @VasiliAngapov yes I see those tags